# I am trying to install Epson V200 scanner drivers onto Ubuntu 14.10

Tags: drivers, printing, 14.10, scanner, epson

I am trying to install Epson V200 scanner drivers onto Ubuntu 14.10. And I have downloaded the drivers directly from the Epson site for the above scanner. But when I try to install them I get the following error message for the following driver:

```
Driver Iscan-plugin-gt-f670 Dependency is notsatisfied: iscan (>=2.16)
```

What is the problem? And what can I do to fix it?

Answer (score 1):

I believe you have to install 3 separate drivers in a particular order.  Here is an example for 32 bit machine:

```
1. iscan-data_1.34.0-1_all.deb`

2.iscan_2.30.1-1~usb0.1.ltdl7_i386.deb

3.iscan-plugin-gt-f670_2.1.2-1_i386.deb
```

In short,  1st is "data", 2nd is "ltdl7" and 3rd is plug in. Make sure you download deb files (not the md5 or others)

Answer (score 0):

*Then install the newest iscan realease in the repository:*

*`apt-get install iscan`*

EDIT:

Sorry, iscan is **not** in the standard repository.

Comment: Update your answer with an explanation howto use this repository!

Comment: @SPRBRN : Sorry, I didn't find any information about this yet.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for that. Those drivers load up this time, with no error messages, in the order that you gave.

But unfortunately The v200 scanner still does not work. I am at a loss, loads of people seem to have the same problem, but as yet no positive answers to the problem.

This scanner works fine in windows XP. But i do want to go fully Linux Ubuntu. and dump windows.

Comment: What program are you using to scan? simple scan, image scan. .....

Answer (score 0):

1. iscan-data_1.34.0-1_all.deb

2.iscan_2.30.1-1~usb0.1.ltdl7_i386.deb

3.iscan-plugin-gt-f670_2.1.2-1_i386.deb '

I installed the above three in the order as above.
Was unable to get scanner to work. Rebooted my machine and was then able to to get the V200 to scan a document, but am unable to scan a photograph from a slide of negative. Any advice would be much appreciated.

Comment: Why do you react by creating new answers? You copy the answer from @5thWheel, so reply there with a comment. That keeps him informed and he can reply to your comment. Plus upvote his answer if it helped you even one step further. Inform us, and help future visitors!